# Are Summon - [insert-creature-type-here] cards creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Back in the day we didn't have `Creature - Name` card types, instead we had `Summon - Name` card types. Long ago in magic, cards were printed entirely differently, and this actually creates some interesting situations with the present day rulings. For example, in the past the `Defender` ability was non-existent. There were instead creatures printed `Summon - Wall` and such creatures with the `Wall` subtype were ruled to not be able to attack.

It's supposedly possible now with the introduction of `Defender` that such old walls without `Defender` can actually attack, drastically changing how some cards have been used.

My question is, if my opponent has such a card, `Summon - Wall`, or perhaps `Summon - Goblin`, etc., does that count in the present rulings as a Creature Card? Can I target it with "*destroy non-black creature*", or perhaps "*return target creature to opponent's hand*"? The confusion between my group of players is the word *Creature* is actually not on these cards, and it *is* on every other creature card that's out in this time and age.

Comment: Comprehensive rules glossary: **Wall:** A creature type with no particular rules meaning. Older cards with the Wall creature type but without defender had an unwritten ability that precluded them from attacking. Those cards have received errata in the Oracle card reference to have defender. Some older cards that referenced the Wall creature type have also received errata. See Defender.

Comment: A bit of nitpickery: while these _permanents_ can be destroyed by 'destroy target creature'-type spells, there's actually a salient difference between a _creature_, a _creature card_ and a _creature spell_.  Doom Blade can't 'destroy' e.g. a non-black creature card in your graveyard, but it _can_ destroy a green Beast token like the ones created by various instances of Garruk.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, these cards are MtG cards with the type Creature. A cards official wording is what currently appears in the Oracle Online reference.

From the Comprehensive Rules

> 108.1. Use the Oracle card reference when determining a card’s wording. A card’s Oracle text can be found using the Gatherer card database at http://gatherer.wizards.com.

> Summon (Obsolete)
>   Older creature cards were printed with “Summon [creature type]” on their type lines. All such cards have received errata in the Oracle card reference to say “Creature — [creature type].” (Many of these cards’ creature types have also been updated.) See Creature.

Answer (score 7):

All of those cards have received errata in the official Oracle. If you visit [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com) and look up any of those old cards, you can see the new wording for it. Many creatures gained subtypes, so it's worth checking into. For example, Llanowar Elves went from "Summon Elves" to "Creature - Elf Druid". Also, all Interrupts becames Instants.

Also, you'll find that all those walls will likely have Defender in the Oracle ruling :-)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Possibly not, **if and only if** R&D's Secret Lair is in play:

[image]

P.S. I was just about to correct "in play" to "on the battlefield" there, but actually I don't have to, since I have R&D's Secret Lair in play :P

Comment: In the old rules, a "Summon" card on the battlefield was still called a "creature".

Comment: Yeah, this answer's definitely a bit (a lot) tongue-in-cheek - but I can see trying to argue a fine distinction between old Summon cards and new Creature cards as the sort of thing that can and should happen in an Unglued environment...